# How to tell Apache CXF to use java.util.Date in Spring Configuration

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I am Using CXF to host web services **in a Spring context**, which makes JAX-WS the default binding. And I'm using Java-First, which means annotated endpoint interfaces and classes.

Since default binding for JAX-WS uses `XMLGregorianCalendar` class for dates, when I call my web service passing a `java.util.Date` it is converted to `XMLGregorianCalendar` on the server.

There are many posts and documentation on how to change this to bind date values to `java.util.Date`, but all are related to wsdl2java tool, such as:

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="YOUR_WSDL_LOCATION"
          xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='THE_NAMESPACE_OF_YOUR_SCHEMA']">
      <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                      parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                      printMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime"/>
      </jxb:globalBindings>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Since I'm using Spring, I'm looking for a way to do this in Spring context configuration files (or CXF configuration files). A snippet of my file:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="jaxwsDocumentGroupWsEndpoint" implementor="#documentGroupWsEndpoint" address="/documentGroup">
<!-- SOMETHING TO WRITE HERE TO TELL CXF TO USE java.util.Date ??? -->
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: In case anyone encountered the same problem, I could resolve mine using JAXB annotations. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953433/tell-jaxb-to-unmarshal-xsdatetime-to-date-class-using-annotations

Comment: Can you be more specific, about what artifact you want to customize? If it is JAX-WS artifact (SEI), than provide a Java code for the interface. Or if that is JAXB bean, show us the generated code.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for your problem is hidden into class generation.

You should generate your classes with the following binding:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings generateMixedExtensions="true">
        <jaxb:javaType 
            name="java.util.Calendar" 
            xmlType="xs:dateTime"           
            parseMethod="com.test.DataTypeBinder.unmarshalDateTime" 
            printMethod="com.test.DataTypeBinder.marshalDateTime" />

</jaxb:globalBindings>
```

And include in your class path the following class:

```
public class DataTypeBinder {
private static DateFormat dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); 
    private static DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

    public static Calendar unmarshalDate(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        Date d = null;

        try {
            d = date.parse(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(d);
        return c;
    }

    public static  String marshalDate(Calendar value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return date.format(value.getTime());
    }   


    public static Calendar unmarshalDateTime(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        Date d = null;

        try {
            d = dateTime.parse(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(d);
        return c;
    }

}
```

Then JAXB is going to include in your generated classes the following type declaration:

```
@XmlElement(type = String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected Calendar transactionDate;
```

Comment: This solution may work, but may be worth noting that SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803

Comment: @Forge_7 is there any trade safe solution ?

Comment: @kozla13 simply instantiate the SimpleDateFormat as a local variable whenever it is used, rather than store it as a static (or instance) variable.