# Static method, static variable can it get mutated by multiple threads in web app - jsp

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, methods, static

I am working on this project. There is a class DefaultsHelper which has  :

```
    public  class DefaultsHelper {

    static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") ;

    public static String getDate(int days)
    {
        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar() ;
        c.setTime(new Date()) ;
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
        return df.format(c.getTime()) ;

    }
}
```

In a web app - if two users where viewing a jsp whereby the getDate function was called at the exact same time - is it possible that the df object could get inconsistent and thereby not return expected values?

I think the DefaultsHelper was meant to be a utility class to stop having to instantiate new df objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a new `Calendar` per thread, which is good, but you're using the `SimpleDateFormat` across multiple threads. This would be ok if that class were thread-safe, *but it's not*.

`SimpleDateFormat` is [notorious for being thread-unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/simpledateformat-thread-safety). Simply create a new one for each invocation (i.e. in the method), or, better still, use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to avoid thread issues completely.

On the subject of creating one formatter class as an optimisation, this is a classic example of premature optimisation and inadvertent results. Given that this is within a JSP, the HTTP request/response time will dwarf the instatiation time (and resource requirements) of a new formatter. Make your classes thread-safe and immutable and worry about optimisation when it becomes an issue.

Comment: thanks i thought that might be the case - i would be better off instantiating a new SimpleDateFormat inside this method then or change how the whole thing works ! Saved me a bad one as times in dbase were written this way

Comment: You will enhance your thread safety massively by searching for static instances of SimpleDateFormat within your applications!

Comment: thanks thats great i changed static like so - look ok ?  public static String getDate(int days)
    {
        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar() ;
        c.setTime(new Date()) ; SimpleDateFormat dft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
        return dft.format(c.getTime()) ;

    }