# Processing Java Strings and Dates

Tags: java, date

I need to process a list of Strings which may or may not be times.  When I do receive a time, it will need to be converted from "HH:mm:ss" to number of milliseconds before processing:

```
final String unknownString = getPossibleTime();    

final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
try {
    final Date date = dateFormat.parse(unknownString);
    //date.getTime() is NOT what I want here, since date is set to Jan 1 1970

    final Calendar time = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    time.setTime(date);

    final Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, time.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    final long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    processString(String.valueOf(millis));
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    processString(unknownString);
}
```

This code works, but I really dislike it.  The exception handling is particularly ugly.  Is there a better way to accomplish this without using a library like Joda-Time?

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't this be more suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Why do you need the two calendars?

Comment: maybe avoiding using the calendar? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()

Comment: on date there is a method getTime(); this should return your final long millis if I got it right

Comment: @fGo How can I make sure the date is set to today and not Jan 1 1970 with only one Calendar?  Its possible with the deprecated Date getters (getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds()), but I would prefer not using deprecated methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static long getTimeInMilliseconds(String unknownString) throws ParseException {

   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String dateString = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

   DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   return timeFormat.parse(dateString + " " + unknownString).getTime();
}
```

Handle the ParseException outside of this method however you'd like.  I.e. ("No time information provided"... or "unknown time format"... etc.)

`.getTime()` returns the time in milliseconds.  It's part of the `java.util.Date` API.

Comment: The problem is that `date` is set to Jan 1 1970, not the current day.  I'll update the code above with a comment to make that more clear.

Comment: @dbryne Good catch - I tried something a bit different.  Check again.

Comment: [SimpleDateFormat is not threadsafe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803) so using static instances carries risk.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you first check if the input is actually of HH:mm:ss format. You can do this by trying match input to regex `[0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9]?[0-9]` first and if it matches then treat it as date otherwise call processString(unknownString);

Comment: `(\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)` so you don't allow 30:73:99 as a valid time.