# Nearly always write classes with no state as singletons?

Tags: java, singleton

Today I saw the following JavaFX related code in a project:

```
issueComboBox.setConverter(new IntegerStringConverter());
yearComboBox.setConverter(new IntegerStringConverter());
```

and thought: Do I really need to create two instances of IntegerStringConverter?

IntegerStringConverter has the following code:

```
public class IntegerStringConverter extends StringConverter<Integer> {

    @Override public Integer fromString(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        value = value.trim();

        if (value.length() < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        return Integer.valueOf(value);
    }

    @Override public String toString(Integer value) {

        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return (Integer.toString(((Integer)value).intValue()));
    }
}
```

So I don't need two instances, because there is no state in IntegerStringConverter, also 
not in StringConverter.
If I could rewrite the class I would rewrite it as a singleton, like that:

```
public final class IntegerStringConverter extends StringConverter<Integer> {

    public static final IntegerStringConverter INSTANCE = new IntegerStringConverter();

    private IntegerStringConverter() { }

    @Override public Integer fromString(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        value = value.trim();

        if (value.length() < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        return Integer.valueOf(value);
    }

    @Override public String toString(Integer value) {

        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return (Integer.toString(((Integer)value).intValue()));
    }
}
```

So users of this class can't create multiple instances:

```
issueComboBox.setConverter(IntegerStringConverter.INSTANCE);
yearComboBox.setConverter(IntegerStringConverter.INSTANCE);
```

Its a class from javafx.util.converter package.
I think it isn't implemented in the way i suggested because the JavaFX developers
want to give us the possibility to extend this class.

**The point of the matter is, is it nearly always a good idea to implement classes (
which are not pure helper classes with only static methods) with
no state as singletons to prevent multiple instantiations for memory and performance 
reasons?**

Comment: How about implementing those methods as static?

Comment: @gunar: this is probably not an option, because you have to implement all methods of `StringConverter` which could not be static!

Answer (score 1):

*I can't exactly say why exactly was it done that way in JavaFX.*

One possible explanation can be that
Singleton is bad for inheritance. You can extend `IntegerStringConvertor` in future to provide more specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If no method of your `IntegerStringConverter` class will change any values of the members in this class, you could pass it as a singleton. In your case it could be done like this, because you don't even have a member in your class

But imagine, you have a member field in this class which will be modified due to method calls, this is not a good idea. It's like the point, that you have to be thread safe in this case. This is like the question, why not using a single instance of `SimpleDateFormat` for multiple calls. Because it is not thread safe! See: [Why is Java's SimpleDateFormat not thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/simpledateformat-thread-safety)

So, this would be a **bad idea**:

```
public class Foo {
    public static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();

    private int value = 0;

    public void changeIt() {
        value++;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class PrintThingy {
    private static void print(Foo foo) {
        foo.changeIt();
        System.out.println(foo.getValue());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(Foo.INSTANCE);  // prints 1
        print(Foo.INSTANCE);  // prints 2 - huh!
    }
}
```

So, it really depends on what you're doing in this singleton class and what will be done in the methods you're passing your singleton instance through!