# How to use FastDateFormat to create Date object using String

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang

I used SimpleDataFormat and it seems to be not a very thread safe thing to use. Then I found that [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html) is the alternative to this problem. But I'm trying to figure out how to use it in order to parse String with Date and Time.

Here is a explanation on why wrong use of SimpleDateFormat is bad : [Why is Java's SimpleDateFormat not thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/simpledateformat-thread-safety)

Problem in code :
I have following string

```
String date = "2014-04-27'T'13:45:31";
```

I need to convert that into `Date`. But in a thread safe way. I would like to use something related to `FastDateFormat`. Not the `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is threadsafe if a new instance is created each time a conversion needs to be done.

Comment: agree, But like to know how to use FastDateFormat as well.

Comment: What is your concrete problem?

The basic recipe:
- Create a FastDateFormat instance using the static method suiting your specific needs.
- Use this to parse the string and obtain a Java Date object.

That's it. Where are you running into issues?

Comment: From the JavaDoc you linked: `Only formatting is supported ...` so there is no way to parse a String into a Date object.

Comment: Parsing is supported since commons-lang 3.2.

Comment: Another alternative is to use Joda Time instead, which has thread-safe formatters... and is a cleaner date/time API to start with.

Comment: Thank you @Ray. I was using 3.0. When i changed it to 3.2 it can be used similar to the SimpleDateFormat. If you answer that I'll accept it. Thank you all for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing is supported since commons-lang 3.2.

The basic recipe:

1. Create a [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html) instance using the static method suiting your specific needs.
2. Use this to parse the string and obtain a Java Date object.

That's it.