# How to use SimpleDataFomat in JEE code?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, synchronization, thread-safety, simpledateformat

SimpleDataFomat is not thread safe and it is not recommended to use Synchronize in JEE.
How to handle this in JEE ?

Thanks

Comment: 1. just don't. Use the java.time api. 2. Just create a SimpleDateFormat when you need one. You seem to think that all thread-safety issues are solved using synchronized here and there. That's far from the truth. And there is no problem in synchronizing a piece of code that needs to be synchronized in Java EE. Don't know where you got that.

Comment: i think this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/simpledateformat-thread-safety

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick to the SimpleDateFormatter class don't share the SimpleDateFormatter object in a member variable but just create a new one inside the method to be on the safe side. Another approach is to put it in a ThreadLocal.