# Is it a bad practice to save thread local values in static final field?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I came across following code in a legacy system,

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> dateFormatThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal(){

    @Override
    protected Object initialValue() {
        //Set initial value
        return new SimpleDateFormat("");
    }
};


private static final DateFormat someValue = dateFormatThreadLocal.get();
```

However, I have following questions.

1.) Is it a good idea to define thread locals as final. ( I know static is fine)

2.) Is it a good idea to hold thread local.get() call in a static (or both static and final) instance variable? ( if we do this doesn't it hinder the whole purpose of having thread-local at first place )

Comment: FYI if you have java 8, you can use `DateTimeFormatter` which is threadsafe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35818373/360211

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.) Is it a good idea to define thread locals as final. ( I know static is fine)

If you are not assigning to `dateFormatThreadLocal` then `final` makes no difference. However, it's generally a good idea, because it prevents you from *accidentally* assigning to it.

> 2.) Is it a good idea to hold thread local.get() call in a static (or both static and final) instance variable? ( if we do this doesn't it hinder the whole purpose of having thread-local at first place )

No it is not. Actually, if you *do* do this then it defeats the whole purpose of having thread-local in the first place.

Whichever thread happens to load the class first will retrieve its SimpleDateFormat, and store a reference to that object in `someValue`. And then whenever you use `someValue`, the current thread will use *that thread's* SimpleDateFormat (that it got before) instead of calling `dateFormatThreadLocal.get()` and getting its own one.

If you're using ThreadLocal then presumably you *don't* want every thread to use the same object - otherwise why bother using it?