# Parse and format date

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I have the following code for taking a date in the form of a string `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (UTC timezone) and turning it into `EEEE d(st, nd, rd, th) MMMM yyyy HH:mm` (device's default timezone).

However, my problem with the way I have done it is the code looks messy and inefficient. Is there a way to achieve what I want without formating and parsing the same date so many times to make it more efficient? Or any other improvements?

Preferably supporting Android API level 14.

---

```
String inputExample = "2017-06-28 22:44:55";

//Converts UTC to Device Default (Local)
private String convertUTC(String dateStr) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date temp = df.parse(dateStr);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        String local = df.format(temp);
        Date localDate = df.parse(dateStr);
        SimpleDateFormat outputDF1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE ");
        SimpleDateFormat outputDF2 = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMMM yyyy HH:mm");
        return outputDF1.format(temp) + prefix(local) + outputDF2.format(temp);
    } catch(java.text.ParseException pE) {
        Log.e("", "Parse Exception", pE);
        return null;
    }
}

private String prefix(String dateStr) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat outputDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date temp = outputDF.parse(dateStr);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
        int d = Integer.parseInt(df.format(temp));
        if(1 <= d && d <= 31) {
            if(11 <= d && d <= 13)
                return d + "th";
            switch (d % 10) {
                case 1: return d + "st";
                case 2: return d + "nd";
                case 3: return d + "rd";
                default: return d + "th";
            }
        }
        Log.e("", "Null Date");
        return null;
    } catch(java.text.ParseException pE) {
        Log.e("", "Parse Exception", pE);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for pointing that out. I'll post it there

Comment: You have to profile your code to find out what causes poor performance. As for the "messy" part - well, java.util.date APIs are widely considered "messy", there's not a lot you can do. Refactor the code to find ways to make it cleaner. Make sure you have a bulletproof suite of unit tests before you start refactoring.

Comment: If it is decided that this question is closed here follow it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166935/parse-and-format-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `SimpleDateFormat` there's probably not much to improve. As your output format has `EEEE` (day of the week) and `MMMM` (month name), you'll have to parse the date in order to know the values for those. Without using a date formatter, you'll have to do lots of `if`'s to get the respective names for each value.

---

In Android, as an alternative to `SimpleDateFormat`, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes, together with the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

All classes are below the `org.threeten.bp` package. In the code below I'm  also using `Locale.ENGLISH`, otherwise it'll use the system's default (as mine is not English and I'm assuming yours is):

```
String inputExample = "2017-06-28 22:44:55";
// parser for input
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
// parse the date and set to UTC
ZonedDateTime z = LocalDateTime.parse(inputExample, parser).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

// map of custom values - map each numeric value to its string with suffix (st, nd...)
Map<Long, String> textLookup = new HashMap<Long, String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
    String suffix = "";
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
    case 21:
    case 31:
        suffix = "st";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 22:
        suffix = "nd";
        break;
    case 3:
    case 23:
        suffix = "rd";
        break;
    default:
        suffix = "th";
    }
    textLookup.put((long) i, i + suffix);
}
// output formatter
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // day of week
    .appendPattern("EEEE ")
    // append day with suffix (use map of custom values)
    .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, textLookup)
    // rest of pattern
    .appendPattern(" MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
    // create formatter with English locale
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

// print date, convert it to device default timezone
System.out.println(fmt.format(z.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

The output will be:

> Wednesday 28th June 2017 19:44

The time was set to `19:44` because my default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo` (in **UTC-03:00**).

Not sure if it's less messy enough for you, but at least IMO it's much more clear than `SimpleDateFormat`. Just 2 formatters were created (one for output, another for output). Of course there's the `textLookup` map, but it has only 31 entries and the formatters can be reused as well.

And [`SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/why-is-javas-simpledateformat-not-thread-safe), while [the new API is](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).