# In my program am getting intermittently ParseException while doing SimpleDateFormat.parse

Tags: java, date, apache-storm, simpledateformat

In my program I am getting intermittently a `ParseException` while doing `SimpleDateFormat.parse`.

I have written one apache storm bolt, in that I am parsing the input date `"2018-02-26 18:13:32 UTC"`.

This exception is not thrown for every input date. Also, I have printed the input date in error log. Visually there are no issues with input date format.

But I've got the `ParseException` for intermittent inputs.

I doubt is that because it is concurrent environment.

Following is the code snippet:

```
utcDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'");
```

Comment: Can you add examples of both input that fails and input that doesn't?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: As long as you instantiate `SimpleDateFormat` every time you want to parse an input then it should be thread-safe (although not ideal in terms of performance). And your pattern using escaping "UTC" will only work if you also set the timezone of the newly created formatter to "UTC". But strictly avoid reusing the formatter in multi-thread-environment.

Answer (score 4):

> I doubt is that because it is concurrent environment.

Actually, that's the most probable cause, because `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe. Check here an analysis of the problem and how to fix it: https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue172.html

Apart from that, "UTC" is an important information (it indicates that, well, the date is in UTC), so you can't treat it as a literal (inside quotes). The formatter you created is ignoring that the date is in UTC (because inside quotes it's treated as *"some text"*, not as *"it's in UTC"*), so it's actually using the JVM default timezone (which can't necessarily be UTC).

To correctly parse **UTC**, you must use the `z` pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = sdf.parse("2018-02-26 18:13:32 UTC");
```

But if you're using Java 8 or higher, just use the new date API:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // parse date and time
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ")
    // parse UTC
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "UTC")
    // create the formatter
    .toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-02-26 18:13:32 UTC", fmt);
```

It seems more complicated at first, but this new API provides lots of different date-time types and much more options to parse and format them.

And more important: **it's thread safe**.

#### UPDATE:

As suggested in the comments, you can also do:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-02-26 18:13:32 UTC", fmt);
```

If you still need to work with `java.util.Date`, it's easy to convert:

```
Date javaUtilDate = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

The `OffsetDateTime` class also has a `toInstant()` method, so both can be converted to `Date`.

Comment: Depending on the requirements `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz")` may be all the OP needs (will work for parsing into a `ZonedDateTime`, you can always convert to `OffsetDateTime` if you want).

Comment: @OleV.V. That's interesting, why **zzz** doesn't work with `OffsetDateTime`? I think I need to study more...

Comment: I discovered once I had to parse a string that contained both an offset and a time zone name. Parsing into an `OffsetDateTime` would ignore the time zone, and parsing into a `ZonedDateTime` would ignore the offset. And `zzz` counts as zone name.

Comment: @OleV.V. I thought that "UTC" was a synonym for "Z" (zero offset), not a zone name. But it seems I was wrong...

Comment: All I say is that it *can* be parsed as a zone name. Whether that makes sense or not? Your judgement is as good as mine.

Comment: Thanks I have updated  my code to     DateTimeFormatter utcDateFormatter  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
DateTimeFormatter Instantformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

try {

String instantDate = Instantformatter.format(utcDateFormatter.parse(inputDate));

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` is not threadsafe and you really can get a `ParseException`  in the concurrent environment.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/why-is-javas-simpledateformat-not-thread-safe) for details.

For Java 8 you can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) which is threadsafe.

Comment: For Java 6 & 7, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* library, a back-port Of much of the *java.time* functionality. The legacy date-time classes are a wretched mess and should be avoided.

Comment: @MikeAdamenko I believe Joda-Time is a step forward, but it’s a finished project with no major development these days. So if you’re fine with an external dependency, why not go for the future-proof replacement for Joda-Time, java.time through the mentioned backport? The home page you are linking to says “Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).”

Comment: @MikeAdamenko The reason to use *ThreeTen-Backport* rather than *Joda-Time* is the close parallel in API between *java.time* and *ThreeTen-Backport*. When you do eventually move to Java 8 or later, you’ll need do little more to your codebase than change your `import` statements when you decide to phase out use of the back-port.

Comment: @BasilBourque  yes, it make sense, agree with you